# fonts IE8 not displaying

Tags: css, fonts

I dont really understand much about fonts, I have donwloaded several font from sites like font squirrel, dafont,  and when I try installing in my joomla site, ( I only need to have this font on my menu top) no whole body nor h1,h2  tags.

The font dont display correclty, I tested a font on my personal compuet at home IE9and was able to have it working , but in IE 8 here at job it does not display ...   So what would be the best way to have it working on IE8, what is the font type , and css declaration I need?  Thank you very much

here are two fonts:

```
    @font-face {
     font-family: Opificio;
     src: url("../fonts/Opificio.eot") /* EOT file for IE */
    }
    @font-face {
     font-family: Opificio;
     src: url("../fonts/Ofificio.TTF") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
    }



    @font-face {
     font-family: chiser;
     src: url("../fonts/chiser.eot") /* EOT file for IE */
    }
    @font-face {
     font-family: chiser;
     src: url("../fonts/chiser.TTF") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
    }


#tx-navigation{
    font-family:"Opificio";
    font-size:11px;
    }


That works


#tx-navigation{
    font-family:"chiser";
    font-size:11px;
    }

Doesnt work
```

Comment: what does it look like? your question isn't well defined.

Comment: The only thing i know about fonts is that when you install one on -your- computer it won't work on -another- one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font on a web site will get displayed depending on the **installed fonts** on the system, that's why you should use the [font-family](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp) CSS Property.

[EDIT] You can also try to use [embeded fonts](http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol3/css_no15.htm).

Comment: Then see [here](http://randsco.com/index.php/2009/07/04/p680) to build a cross-browser font CSS. Your question is really unclear about what works and what doesn't

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that when it comes to websites, the user's browser and computer need to have the font for it to work. Installing it on your own machine will only work for you.

The only exception to this is of you are usinga webfont (see here [Webfonts Quick guide](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webfonts/quick/)) but again this depends on the user's browser as not all current browsers fully support it.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes it a bit clearer.  Looking at the code, the only thing I can say is it might be an issue with the "Chiser" font and IE8. Do you have a live link? I have IE8 at work so I can compare it to my FF6.0

Comment: Another quick thought, could your work network/firewall be blocking the font Chiser font?